# WCF modify config file

Tags: wcf, web-config

I am trying to modify the WCF behaviors programatically (i.e modify config file section).

```
BehaviorsSection  bhsSection = (BehaviorsSection)this.configFile.GetSection("system.serviceModel/behaviors");
```

After I retrieve the section I want to be able to update/modify the `serviceMetadata` section and save the file.

Any ideas on how to proceed after I have loaded the section? I am unable to locate an object I can cast and change the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some sample code that opens the config file for the currently executing app and modifies the serviceMetadata element.

```
static void FindServiceMetadata()
{
  var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
  var sg = ServiceModelSectionGroup.GetSectionGroup(config);
  foreach (ServiceBehaviorElement behavior in sg.Behaviors.ServiceBehaviors)
  {
    foreach (var item in behavior)
    {
      var metadata = item as ServiceMetadataPublishingElement;
      if (metadata == null) continue;
      metadata.HttpsGetEnabled = true;
    }
  }
  config.Save();
}
```

This assumes a config file that contains a system.serviceModel section something like the following:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="test">
          <serviceMetadata />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```